# array of JButtons with ActionListener and event on key space

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

I have an array of `JButtons` and I have added an `ActionListener` on them.

Then i put a `new Thread(){ public void run(){} }.start();`. The background of the current `JButton` will be red and after 3 sec it'll turn white and the next button in the array will get red.

Now I want to add a `KeyEvent` for <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.  The idea is that when the background is red and I type <kbd>SPACE</kbd>it should focus the current button an do the action listener for him.  After 3 sec when I type <kbd>SPACE</kbd> again should press the next button in the array.

I need a solution for this.

Comment: -1 This is StackOverflow. If you want someone to code for you go post on Careers.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Consider posting code, a small program that compiles, runs, shows your problem and has no code unrelated to your problem or to getting the code to run, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this type of thing before, if I'm not mistaken, it's about providing functionality to a disabled user (if not, that's where I've seen it before).

First of all...NEVER, EVER create/modify ANY UI component from any `Thread` other then the Event Dispatching Thread.  In fact, for this question, I doubt you actually need any threads.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for information.

You also, shouldn't need any type of `KeyListener` either.  At worst, you might need to supply a [Key Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), but under most look and feels, <kbd>Space</kbd> is supported as a "default" accept action, like <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

What you really want to do, is simply move the focus to the highlighted button instead.

```
public class TestHelpButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestHelpButton();
    }

    public TestHelpButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[]{
            new JButton(new BasicAction("Don't Panic")),
            new JButton(new BasicAction("Panic")),
            new JButton(new BasicAction("Cup of Tea")),
            new JButton(new BasicAction("Destory the world")),};
        private int activeIndex = -1;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            for (JButton btn : buttons) {
                add(btn);
            }

            updateSelection();

            Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    updateSelection();
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void updateSelection() {
            if (activeIndex >= 0) {
                JButton btn = buttons[activeIndex];
                btn.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }

            activeIndex++;
            if (activeIndex > buttons.length - 1) {
                activeIndex = 0;
            }
            JButton btn = buttons[activeIndex];
            btn.setBackground(Color.RED);
            btn.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }

    public class BasicAction extends AbstractAction {

        public BasicAction(String text) {
            putValue(NAME, text);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, getValue(NAME), "Helper", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

The only reason I'm providing a working example is based on my assumption that this is to provide additional support to a disabled user.